# uint16_t in array of char

Tags: c, tftp

For a school project, I have to develop a TFTP server in C.
I have to build a packet in a array of char like this :

```
 2 bytes    2 bytes    n bytes
+--------+-----------+--------+
|  CODE  |  Block #  |  Data  |
+--------+-----------+--------+
```

Here is how I build this packet:

```
int tftp_make_data(char *buffer, size_t *length, uint16_t block, const char *data, size_t n) {
    memset(buffer, 0, *length);
    *length = 0;
    *(buffer) = DATA;
    *length += sizeof(uint16_t);
    *(buffer + *length) = block;
    *length += sizeof(uint16_t);
    memcpy(buffer + *length, data, n);
    *length += n;

    return 0;
}
```

This function fill `buffer` with the packet content and fill `length` with the size of the packet.
This works fine if `block` is lower than 128. If it's greeter than 128, it becomes -128.

Can you help me?

Comment: `*(buffer + *length) = block;` - you're assigning a `uint16_t` to a `char` (which is apparently `signed` on your platform, as most others). May want to rethink that.

Comment: I used an array of uint8_t and it seems to work. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless something is one byte in size, you cannot assign it to `*buffer`. Both of these assignments are incorrect:

```
*(buffer) = DATA;
*(buffer + *length) = block;
```

When you are writing `uint16_t`, use `memcpy`:

```
uint16_t dataToWrite = ...;
memcpy(buffer + *length, &dataToWrite, sizeof(uint16_t));
```

You are not done yet, because you need to decide what to assign `dataToWrite`. If you do this

```
uint16_t dataToWrite = block;
```

the data sent over the wire will be in hardware-specific order, which should never happen. Instead, you need to use one of [`hton`-family functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/htonl.html) to convert your number to network format:

```
uint16_t dataToWrite = htons(block);
```

> I check it on the same machine, just with
>
> ```
> printf("block : %d\n", packet[sizeof(uint_16)]);
> ```

This is incorrect, for the same reason as the assignment: `packet[sizeof(uint_16)]` makes an `int` or `unsigned int` from the `char`/`uint8_t` value stored at position `sizeof(uint_16)`, and it also ignores the other byte.

To fix this you need to use `memcpy` again. Of course, if you used `htons` on the writing side, you need to use `ntohs` before printing:

```
uint16_t dataToPrint;
memcpy(dataToPrint, &packet[sizeof(uint16_t)], sizeof(uint16_t));
dataToPrint = ntohs(dataToPrint);
printf("block : %u\n", dataToPrint);
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me.
Maybe it's because I use an array of char (which is signed)?
When I use an array of uint8_t, it works :)

Comment: Hit enter while typing :)

Comment: @Mathieu It is still not clear what specifically does not work, though.

Comment: When I use `memcpy` to copy a `uint16_t`, it still become negative when it greeter than 128

Comment: @Mathieu How do you check if it's negative or positive? Using debugger for that wouldn't work. Do you check it on the receiving side? Your receiving side could have a bug, too.

Comment: I check it on the same machine, just with `printf("block : %d\n", packet[sizeof(uint_16)]);`
No networking yet

Comment: Thank you, it works and that make sense for me.
You rock!

Comment: @Mathieu Regarding the edit, the call for printing has to be `ntohs` to "undo" the effect of `htons`.